# Difference between SMB and NAS

Tags: network-attached-storage, server-message-block

I am getting aboard my family businesses and every thing is made with Microsoft. I see that 90% of the processes can be done with free software, and in this case, file sharing. My father always complained that sharing folders with samba was too slow for the system to run properly on larger databases (COBOL) so he always recommended Windows Server for our clients.

When studding, I always installed Samba Server on my development machine and shared the folders editing smbd.conf, so in my mind, the way to share folders on the network would involve SMB. But, I never stopped to think about NAS, which also was made to share files on a network.

I know that SMB is a protocol that incorporate many other functions, but the question remains.

- What is the difference between SMB and NAS in it's file sharing capabilities?
- Which one to use in this case?
- What other functions SMB provide that NAS did not implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not similar things.

NAS means Network Attached Storage, which is a computer designed for hard disk storage shared among multiple clients.

A NAS can implement multiple protocols like SMB, NFS and AppleTalk to support different clients to connect to the database.

SMB protocol is the native protocol Windows uses for filesharing. So, any computer that has an SMB server can be used for Windows clients and filesharing.